# How to extract names from unordered data string using regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I need to extract the names of the people from the following sentence.

---

**Input:** *BENCH: MAHAJAN, MEHR CHAND BENCH: MAHAJAN, MEHR CHAND DAS, SUDHI RANJAN BOSE, VIVIAN HASAN, GHULAM CITATION: 1953 AIR 28 1953 SCR 197*

**Output:** *MEHR CHAND MAHAJAN, MEHR CHAND MAHAJAN,  SUDHI RANJAN DAS,  VIVIAN BOSE,  GHULAM HASAN*

---

For extracting the name from the first part of the sentence, I used the following code.

```
bench = re.search('BENCH: (.*?) BENCH', contents)
if bench:
    bench = bench.group(1)
    bench = ' '.join(reversed(bench.split(",")))
    print(bench)
```

**Output:** *MEHR CHAND MAHAJAN*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regex to match the names in your input data:

```regex
((?:\w+), (?:\w+(?: \w+)?))(?= BENCH:| CITATION:| \w+,)
```

This looks for a word (`\w+`), followed by a comma and then one or two words separated by a space (`\w+(?: \w+)?`), and then uses a forward lookahead to assert that those words must be followed by one of `BENCH:`, `CITATION:` or another word followed by a comma (`\w+,`).

```py
names = re.findall(r'((?:\w+), (?:\w+(?: \w+)?))(?= BENCH:| CITATION:| \w+,)', contents)
```

For your sample data, this yields:

```
['MAHAJAN, MEHR CHAND', 'MAHAJAN, MEHR CHAND', 'DAS, SUDHI RANJAN', 'BOSE, VIVIAN', 'HASAN, GHULAM']
```

This list can then be reformatted as you desire:

```py
names = ', '.join((map(lambda n:' '.join(n.split(', ')[-1::-1]), names)))
```

Output:

```
'MEHR CHAND MAHAJAN, MEHR CHAND MAHAJAN, SUDHI RANJAN DAS, VIVIAN BOSE, GHULAM HASAN'
```